# How to rewrite $\sum_i \left| \mathbf{x}_i^{T} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}_i - y_i \right|^2$ in vector norm sense?

Tags: linear-algebra

How to rewrite $\sum_{i=1}^p \left| \mathbf{x}_i^{T} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}_i - y_i \right|^2$ in vector norm sense,

where $\{\mathbf{x}_i \in \mathbb{R}^n\}_{i=1}^p$, $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^p$, and $y_i$ is an $i$th element of $\mathbf{y}$.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is an $n \times p$ matrix with columns $x_1, \ldots, x_p$, then
$$\sum_{i=1}^p |x_i^\top A x_i - y_i|^2 = \|\operatorname{diag}(X^\top A X) - y\|^2_2.$$